# apache2 Has No Access to Files

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a terrible problem.

Yesterday, I installed LAMP, and I used `sudo chown` and `sudo chmod` to set the permissions on all of the www files. Now, I don't know how to reset it to the default permissions.

Probably apache2 doesn't have permissions to the files (403 error "forbidden")

Comment: What did you `chown` and `chmod` the files to?

Comment: /var/www and files & directories inside

Comment: No. Who did you `chown` the files to (apache, root, etc.)? What are the permissions (755, 600, etc.)? Do an `ls -l /var/www` and post it.

Answer (score 0):

there's not really enough information to know what's going on here, but one approach might simply be to uninstall (purge), clear all the apache files out, and then reinstall...

these are the commands I would run:

```
# apt-get purge apache2
# rm -rf /var/log/apache2
# rm -rf /var/cache/apache2
# rm -rf /var/www/*
# rm -rf /etc/apache2
# apt-get install apache2
```

note that they will need to be run as root (i.e. with `sudo`) -- the `#` indicates a root prompt.  also, be sure to back up anything that you've changed (although if you've just installed it, that shouldn't be too much)

edit:

if all you've done is mangle the permissions on `/var/www`, then just:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
find /var/www/ -type f -exec sudo chmod 644 {} \;
find /var/www/ -type d -exec sudo chmod 755 {} \;
```

note that all you need for it to work is for the apache user (`www-data`) to have read access to these files, generally -- they don't *need* to be owned by `www-data`